# Editor for date time value displaying incorrect value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Ok so this is my editor for date time value:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestimonialCreatedOn)
```

In the code is shows AM time as correct value:

```
<input id="TestimonialCreatedOn-visible" name="TestimonialCreatedOn-visible" value="20/02/2018 11:08:06 AM" data-role="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" class="k-input valid" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" type="text">
```

But for the date time picker it's showing PM:

[image]

Does anyone know why it's not showing AM also the time is wrong, it should show

11:08 PM not 9:38 PM

Cheers

> UPDATE: If I use this to set my model value
>   `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.Now;` then save the value from
>   my editor to the data base the correct time zone value is stored in
>   the database although the incorrect time is displayed in the date time
>   editor.
>
> Now if I set the following to utc `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;` the wrong value is stored in database.

So here is an example:
I have set my model value to this `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;`
Now my editor displays the correct time:

[image]

But if I save that value I get this value in database:
`2018-02-19 22:30:00.000`
Which you can see here:

[image]

So The timezones do not match, no matter which method I use `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;` or `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Probably not related, but just to get it out of the way, what Time Zone are you in?

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: @gilliduck in Australian Central Daylight Time (ACDT)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's built into nop commerce so not sure

Comment: I use this to set it `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: ACDT is GMT + 10:30 (and 11:08AM + 10:30 = 9:38PM) so appears to be an issue with converting to UTC

Comment: What do you mean by "the wrong value is stored"? Aren't you storing the values in GTC and then presenting them in the user's time zone?

Comment: @RufusL I mean I get a time which is not correct. hmm I have never worked with datetime editor so not sure. I figure if I set the model as date time value the editor should know how to work with it

Comment: @chrisc, Looking at some similar questions on the nopCommerce site, it appears that you should be creating and storing your dates in UTC (i.e you should be using `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;`) and it will be displayed correctly in the users time zone

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see my updated question I provided an example of what happens when I do this. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @chrisc, I have not used nopCommerce, so don't really know in what format that control posts back its value. You have not shown how your saving the value, but I assume you would need to use `.ToUniversalTime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so @StephenMuecke has pointed me on the right track here.

When initially creating the model the date time value  must use datetime utc like so `model.TestimonialCreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;`

Then when saving the model I needed to convert the time to local user time:

```
var createdOn = _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)model.TestimonialCreatedOn, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

The date time helper `_dateTimeHelper` is a nopcommerce service and can be initialized in the constructor or can be resolved using EngineContext like so:

```
var _dateTimeHelper = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IDateTimeHelper>();
```

Hope this helps others. Thanks Stephen Muecke

Also to convert back for local time you can use:

```
_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)model.TestimonialCreatedOn, DateTimeKind.Local))
```